# let tr = event.target.parentElement.children; console.log(tr) // мне надо получить то что написано в td

Tags: javascript

let tr = event.target.parentElement.children;
console.log(tr) //  HTMLCollection(6) [td, td, td, td, td, td];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
let tr = [...event.target.parentElement.children].map(td => td.innerText);
console.log(tr);
```

Comment: spasibo dorogoi